# Method in Ajax other than POST and GET

Tags: ajax

I was asked in an interview what are the methods in AJAX other than GET and POST. I googled but I couldn't find any . Could someone please tell me.

Comment: I wonder how you googled.

Answer (score 0):

```
HEAD    Same as GET but returns only HTTP headers and no document body
PUT     Uploads a representation of the specified URI
DELETE  Deletes the specified resource
OPTIONS Returns the HTTP methods that the server supports
```

These are generally used methods
Also see detail about

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are four types of calls you cand do to a REST API GET,POST,PUT and DELETE. PUT should be suposedly used to modify already existing data while DELETE should be used to eliminate data. Still due to convention, PUT and DELETE are barely used. Here are a couple of examples of PUT and DELETE Ajax calls

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlCalltoDeleteResource),
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(data) {
       alert('Deleted');
    },
    error: function(data) {
       alert('Not Deleted');
    },
});



 $.ajax({
  url: urlToUpdate,
  type: 'PUT',
  data: "name=NameToUpdate",
  success: function(data) {
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```